# Kodaira dimension of algebraic fiber spaces

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $\pi:X \longrightarrow C$ be a smooth projective family of varieties over a curve $C$. Fix a point $0\in C$ and assume the fiber $X_{0}$ has nonnegative Kodaira dimension. Is it possible to prove that the generic fiber has nonnegative Kodaira dimension?(without using invariance of plurigenera)